# how to find the key in dictionary which holds the last appearance of one value(Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:
some_dic = {65: 5, 67: 5, 69: 5}
and I would like to get the the key which holds the last appearance of a value.
for example:

```
>> some_dic.keys()
dict_keys([65, 67, 69])
in this example, I would like to get 69.
```

how do I do that?
i tried to convert some_dic.keys() to a list and then use the function reverse()
but of course, it does not lead to anywhere..

Comment: Python dictionaries aren't ordered and there will only be one appearance of the key in the list.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, unless you're using OrderedDict.

Answer (score 4):

There's no meaning to "last appearance" in a standard dictionary; dictionaries are unordered.  Assuming you mean maximum key with that value, you could do something like

```
>>> some_dic = {65:5, 67:5, 69:5, 71:3}
>>> find_v = 5
>>> max(k for k,v in some_dic.items() if v == find_v)
69
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict`s in python are not ordered. Therefor, you *should not attempt any such thing*.

What you probably want to do, is find an alternative data structure, possibly [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be donde with dictionaries, since they are not ordered.

For example, let's say `some_dic` is:

```
some_dic = {65: 5, 67: 5, 69: 5, 70 : 5, 50 : 5, 40 : 5, 66 : 5}
```

You may want to get `66` as the answer, since it golds the last appeareance of `5`, but the `keys` are:

```
print some_dic.keys()

>>> [65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 40, 50]
```

You may want to use a [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries aren't ordered, so this the "last" key has no meaning. You could get around this by using and `OrderedDict`. However, in this case, it seems that you might just want to find the *highest* key.

One way of doing this:

```
max(key for key in some_dic if some_dic[key] == 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, dict.keys() returns a set-like object, not a list, so the sorted order here is coincidence. To get the maximum key, you can use code like this:

```
>>> some_dic = {65: 5, 67: 5, 69: 5}
>>> some_dic.keys()
dict_keys([65, 67, 69])
>>> max(some_dic.keys())
69
```

But it sounds like you are actually asking for the largest key which has the value 5. This is only slightly more complicated and can be done with a generator expression:

```
>>> some_dic = {65: 5, 67: 5, 69: 5}
>>> max( k for k, v in some_dic.items() if v == 5 )
69
>>> some_dic = {65: 5, 67: 5, 69: 5, 70: 6}
>>> max( k for k, v in some_dic.items() if v == 5 )
69
```

Answer (score 0):

It kinda seems like all you want would be:

```
sorted(some_dic.keys())[-1]
```

That would return `69` since that's the last element in the list returned by the `.keys()` method.